# I cannot produce message to my kafka topic from my java producer

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

Error Message: : `[Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`
.yaml file below:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  kafka-net:
    name: kafka-net
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.6.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - c:/Users/snzey/IdeaProjects/kafka-producer:/bitnami/zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - c:/Users/snzey/IdeaProjects/kafka-producer:/bitnami/kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: DOCKER_INTERNAL://:29092,DOCKER_EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: Please add additional information and use code highlighting.

Comment: Change `${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}` to `localhost`

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer and Johannes for your quick response. I made the change, still not working: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,DOCKER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092

Comment: @Johannes I have simple  java program with a producer and a consumer. Can you please be more specific on what information you need?  Thanks a lot

Comment: You also need DOCKER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092 in the KAFKA_LISTENERS